# Vertical alignment between numbers and arrows

Tags: math-mode, align, vertical-alignment, arrows, text

How would I be able to recreate the following picture:

[image]

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tricky part is centering numbers with a sign. The value of `\tabcolsep` sets (now increases) the distance between columns.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\newlength\onewidth
\settowidth{\onewidth}{$2$}

{\tabcolsep10pt
\begin{tabular}{*{11}{c}}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 &10 & $\cdots$ \\
$\updownarrow$ & $\updownarrow$ & $\updownarrow$ 
& $\updownarrow$ & $\updownarrow$ & $\updownarrow$ 
&$\updownarrow$ & $\updownarrow$ & $\updownarrow$ 
& $\updownarrow$ &\\
0 & \makebox[\onewidth][r]{$-1$} &1 
& \makebox[\onewidth][r]{$-2$} &2
& \makebox[\onewidth][r]{$-3$} &3
& \makebox[\onewidth][r]{$-4$} &4 
& \makebox[\onewidth][r]{$-5$} & $\cdots$
\end{tabular}
}
  
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could use `array` environment. For this particular alignment, `mathtools` provides `\mathXlap{}` class of macros, which negates space occupied by its content. For instance minus `-` inside such command will not be included in alignment.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\uda{\updownarrow}
\newcommand\zneg{\mathllap{-}}
\begin{document}
\[
  \setlength\arraycolsep{9pt}
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
  \begin{array}{*{11}{c}}
    1    & 2       & 3    & 4       & 5    & 6       & 7    & 8       & 9    & 10      & \cdots \\
    \uda & \uda    & \uda & \uda    & \uda & \uda    & \uda & \uda    & \uda & \uda    & \\
    0    & \zneg 1 & 1    & \zneg 2 & 2    & \zneg 3 & 3    & \zneg 4 & 4    & \zneg 5 & \cdots
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]